# A central class that combines other relating classes

Tags: php, oop

I am quite new to OOP idea and and still confused about some concepts. I have written this script to practice OOP, but I am very suspicious of this script, since I feel like I am "inventing" a new way of using OOP that I have never seen others doing it.

**My situation:** I have a long `<form>` in `form.php`, and when that `<form>` is submitted, some data(arrays) need to be handled/encoded in a certain way before storing into the db. When retrieving those data from db, I need to parse the encoded data before output onto the browser.

**So** I decided to break "the way to handle data" in this script into 3 components: `Encode`, `Decode`, `Query`, and make each into a class.

**Now** I have `class.php` that contains 3 classes:

```
class Encode {}

class Decode {}

class Query {}
```

And then I felt like I wanted to combine all three classes into 1 class, so I created:

```
class Form {
  private $encode;
  private $decode;
  private $query;

  public function __construct()
  {
    // instantiate the 3 other classes and store them into properties
  }

  public function encode()
  {
    return $this->encode;
  }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
$form = new Form()
$form->encode()->someMethod();
```

So my question is am I on the right track OR **did I violate some basic principles about OOP?**

It would be great if you could point out where I am misunderstanding OOP, thank you.

Comment: It's a matter of architecture, so it doesn't........Just for addition encode and decode are inversed process thus you can also wrapped them as a same class

Comment: I just feel like I have never seen anyone or any scripts that does this, so I am uncertain whether or not I am fancying something stupid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup right, I can put them together, thanks so much!

Comment: The only thing I would advise you to do is not to instantiate the 3 other classes in your constructor, but set them when creating the classes (see answer from @Dhaval). This will allow you to switch classes (like encode and decode) later on, if encoding algorithms change. Otherwise this is a good way of doing OOP (at least from what I can see your are doing).

Comment: @Seb Just want to make sure I'm understanding you correctly. The reason I don't instantiate in constructor is that if anything happened to those classes I instantiate in my constructor (name changes or class deleted), it's easy for me to detect bugs?

Comment: @Sarah Not so much deleting or name changes, but maybe you want to switch encoding algorithms or use different Query system. You can just create new classes and give them to the constructor without having to touch the class itself. Try to abstract this thought - make them as independent from each other as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the encoding and decoding of the data has nothing to do with the form. You even mention it on your question:

> some data(arrays) need to be handled/encoded in a certain way before storing into **the db**

So imo the encoding should be done at the database layer and at the very least *not* at the form layer.

Also from your example you are reaching through the `Form` object to eventually do stuff with some encoder object:

```
$form->encode()->someMethod();
```

Why do you need access to the encoder from *outside* the `Form`?

Finally you are also stating in a comment in your `Form` constructor that you can `// instantiate the 3 other classes and store them into properties`. I wouldn't not do this like that. Because it introduces tight coupling between the 3 other classes and the thing (in the case `Form`) you instantiate it in. Making your code harder to debug and maintain, introduces hidden dependencies (I cannot see it uses e.f. `Encoder` by looking at the method signature) and makes your code harder to test.

An example of what the above looks like:

```
class SomeDatabaseClass
{
    const ENCODED_FIELDS = [
        'field1'
    ];

    private $dbConnection;

    private $encoder;

    private $decoder;

    public function __construct(\PDO $dbConnection, Encoder $encoder, Decoder $decoder)
    {
        $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection;
        $this->encoder      = $encoder;
        $this->decoder      = $decoder;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbConnection->query('SELECT field1, field2 FROM the_fields');

        return $this->decodeFields($stmt->fetchAll());
    }

    public function saveData($fields)
    {
        $fields = $this->encodeFields($fields);

        // store data in db
    }

    private function decodeFields($fields)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            if (!in_array($name, self::ENCODED_FIELDS, true)) {
                continue;
            }

            $fields[$name] = $this->decoder->decode($value);
        }

        return $fields;
    }

    private function encodeFields($fields)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            if (!in_array($name, self::ENCODED_FIELDS, true)) {
                continue;
            }

            $fields[$name] = $this->encoder->encode($value);
        }

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

This way the form doesn't have to know about encoding / decoding data for a purpose (storing and retrieving data from the db) it isn't responsible for.

And you have decoupled the encoder/decoder from the class making your code more reasonable and testable.

Comment: Hi PeeHaa, you are right, whenever I want to do only 1 of the three tasks, `Encode Decode Query` or perhaps `Info` for later on, I need to instantiate all three classes and pass it in `Form` before I can do anything and that's a pain. However, it's just that `Encode Decode Query` are quite specific to that `<form>` and I somehow have the urge to combine three classes together. Am I better off just leaving the three classes alone into 1 file?

Comment: Oh btw, I had a `Query` class that does all the query, so I didn't need to do any query at all in `Form` class. So `Form` class simple gives access to the other three classes but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class Form {
  private $encode;
  private $decode;
  private $query;

  public function __construct(Encode $encode, Decode $decode, Query $query)
  {
   $this->encode = $encode;
   $this->decode = $decode;
   $this->query = $query
  }

  public function encode()
  {
    return $this->encode;
  }
}


$form = new Form(new Encode, new Decode, new Query)
$form->encode->someMethod();
```

Comment: I just tried it, but the properties are private. And if I make them public, then basically I can change the property into any value.

Comment: when you want to hide your private variables you use getters and setters

Comment: So the last line there's a typo? Because I thought you were trying to access as a property.

Comment: yes.. by mistake I copy pasted the entire code as is..I apologise

Comment: @DhavalChheda, It's php, you don't define the type of arguments

Comment: @ Hey-men-Whatsup .. then how do you implement polymorphism in PHP?

Comment: But you can define the type of arguments (if it's an array or Object) in PHP, and this helps with IDEs displaying type hints.

Comment: right Seb. that is the only way you can pass objects as arguments